# Spring mvc handlerinterceptor is deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Why is the `HandlerInterceptor` deprecated in Spring 5.1.8? Are there any replacements？

While Filter is an option, but I feel it's less convenient than the `HandlerInterceptor` class, itself.

Comment: Where did you see it? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

Comment: I use  spring mvc 5.1.8, IDE indicates that HandlerInterceptor is deprecated. I download the source code and sure of that

Comment: It seems to be a external annotation on intellij

Answer (score 0):

The `HandlerInterceptor` class has not been deprecated in the current version of Spring as of the date of this answer. You can see this since [the Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) doesn't make use of the `@Deprecated` annotation. As such, you should be able to use this class for the foreseeable future without issue.

Comment: It doesn't mentioned HandlerInterceptor is deprecated in java doc but in source code (version 5.1.8),it's deprecated surely

Comment: That's not correct. Based on the latest source code on the master branch, HandlerInterceptor is not deprecated. You can see HandlerInterceptor's source at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.java

Comment: yes, you are right! But what strange is, I download source code in intellij, there is a deprecated annotation on HandlerInterceptor and also when implements HandlerInterceptor it indicates that implements is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

fixed，I put a external annotation by accident